# Is there any way to connect the AiBuilder with Text in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps

I've built an AI with the new AiBuilder by PowerApps. It detects faces. I want to make an App which says "face detected" when it detected a face and "no face detected" when it didn't detect a face. Is there any way to let the Text know that a face is detected? I'm completely new to PowerApps so any help would be appreciated.

I've included my AI Model. I've included text with the above shown text. I turned the visibility off on both texts. Then I set a rule for the "face detected" text called "detected" with the condition: 
`"ObjectDetector1.face >=1"` the action then is `"Visible -> true`.
The text "no face detected" has the rule "not detected" with the condition: "ObjectDetector1.face =0" the action is "Visible -> true. The code for the conditions is probably wrong so can anyone help me out with that? I would appreciate it.

It should display the text "face detected" when he actually detected a face and "no face detected" when the is no face detected. At the moment it shows no text when it detected a face nor didn't detect a face.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that I called my module "face" so it should recognize the ".face". (I hope?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
First(ObjectDetector1.VisionObjects).count >= 1
```

and

```
First(ObjectDetector1.VisionObjects).count = 0
```

were the key! If anyone runs into the same issue.